# Unable to add a HashMap in an Arraylist without deleting the previous element

Tags: java, android, collections, arraylist

My Code:

```
public ArrayList<Map<String, String>> XMLToArray(String Data, Document Doc,
        XMLParser file) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < Doc.getElementsByTagName("item").getLength(); i++) {

        Element e = (Element) Doc.getElementsByTagName("title").item(i);
        Element e2 = (Element) Doc.getElementsByTagName("description")
                .item(i);

        // Element e3 = (Element)Doc.getElementsByTagName("link").item(i);

        map.put("titre", file.getElementValue(e));
        map.put("description", file.getElementValue(e2));

        // map.put("lien", file.getElementValue(e3));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }

    return menuItems;
}
```

In debug, I can see each title and description in the map. When I add my map in the arrayList, all previous key-value in the arraylist are replaced by the current key-value.
So at the end I have a arrayList with 20 same title and description.

How do I add several title and description in the arrayList without erasing all others?

Comment: You're adding the same object to the list multiple times, how do you expect it to be different?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new map for each menuItem. In the example below, I moved the map initializer to the for loop:

```
public ArrayList<Map<String, String>> XMLToArray(String Data, Document Doc, XMLParser file)
 {

    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    for(int i = 0; i < Doc.getElementsByTagName("item").getLength();i++)
    {
      Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

      Element e = (Element)Doc.getElementsByTagName("title").item(i);
      Element e2 = (Element)Doc.getElementsByTagName("description").item(i);

      //Element e3 = (Element)Doc.getElementsByTagName("link").item(i);

      map.put("titre", file.getElementValue(e));
      map.put("description", file.getElementValue(e2));

      //map.put("lien", file.getElementValue(e3));

      // adding HashList to ArrayList
      menuItems.add(map);
  }

 return menuItems;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all it works very weel !
But i don't understand why i need to create each object, i can't use only one object Map and change properties ?

Comment: No, you can't. You are actually adding references to the Map to the ArrayList. And if you only have one Map, your ArrayList will be filled with references which point to the same Map.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the map in the loop:

```
public ArrayList<Map<String, String>> XMLToArray(String Data, Document Doc, XMLParser file) {
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    for(int i = 0; i < Doc.getElementsByTagName("item").getLength(); i++) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element)Doc.getElementsByTagName("title").item(i);
    }
}
```